# Compiling and Running java in Unix ( coming from Windows )

Tags: java, bash, unix, sh

Ok, this is working on windows. My Java app is running and functioning normally

```
javac -classpath .;ojdbc14.jar -g foo.java
java  -classpath .;ojdbc14.jar  foo
```

However, when I do the same thing on Unix I get this error:
    ojdbc14.jar: not found

What am I doing wrong? I know the ";" is telling my shell that ojdbc14.jar is a new command, but I'm not sure how to fix this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use a colon (":") instead of a semicolon (";").

See [Setting the class path (Solaris and Linux)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/classpath.html) vs [Setting the class path (Windows)](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html)

Answer (score 2):

The final solution was:

```
javac -classpath .:ojdbc14.jar -g foo.java
java  -classpath .:ojdbc14.jar  foo
```

Note: Using '.;ojdbc14.jar' removed the initial error message I was getting, but resulted in the following errro:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: foo
```

Answer (score 0):

```
javac -classpath '.;ojdbc14.jar' -g foo.java
java  -classpath '.;ojdbc14.jar'  foo
```

Comment: OK, you're correct that the single quote will prevent the shell from interpreting the ";" as a command separator, but a Unix java isn't going to understand ";" in the classpath.

Comment: *If* java will recognize the semicolon in a classpath on non-Windows platforms, it is neither guaranteed nor documented.

Comment: +1. The -1 was unwarranted. InsDel's solution does work, and is not inherently unhelpful. It might not be the optimal solution, but it is a solution.

Comment: Yeah, but I think James's point is valid - it may not always work.

Answer (score 0):

Use ant, or even better use ant with a continuous build environment like Hudson and a SCM like SVN.