# How to convert a .java file to a .class file?

Tags: java

I am new to Java. I was given some `.java` files and was told if I could convert them, then I could use them. It is for a game bot I am using. They changed to a new API which I don't understand, so the bot won't run unless it is implemented in `.class` files.

Can someone explain me how to convert these `.java` files to fully functional `.class` files?

Comment: Might want to take a look at some of the tutorials posted on the `java` tag wiki page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tagnames=java&sort=info&pagesize=30

Comment: By the way: [Java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_%28programming_language%29) != [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript). You told about a *script* all the time and incorrectly tagged `[javascript]`.

Comment: Related question regarding CLASSPATH setting: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/322098/compiling-and-running-java-in-unix-coming-from-windows ; and distantly related: compiling to .exe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011664/compiling-a-java-program-into-an-exe

Answer (score 5):

You need to compile the `.java` source code to the `.class` byte code. Use a Java compiler like `javac` from Sun's JDK, or if you're using an IDE like Eclipse, it already has a compiler that can generate the `.class` files for you (usually in the `\bin` directory).

#### See also

- [Wikipedia/Java Development Kit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Development_Kit) / [`javac`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javac)
- http://www.eclipse.org/

#### Related links for `javac`

- [Getting Started With Java Tutorial: "Hello World!"](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/cupojava/index.html) / [Common Problems (and their solutions!)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/problems/index.html)
- [The Java Programming Language Compiler - `javac`](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javac/index.html)

  - Manual page: [Solaris](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javac.html)/[Windows](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javac.html)

Comment: ok, thank you..another stupid question.lol.. where do i find such tools to do that? i have the java jdk thing..lol..i'll get the eclipse if that will do what i need it to do to these scripts

Comment: will the javac allow me to laod a script into it then compile them into .class (byte) code which i then need to compile into my gamebots scripts?

Comment: oh my. thank you, this is kinda frwaking me out ..lol..i know nothing about this stuff but want to learn

Comment: @plr: Do the "Hello world" tutorial I linked; that should give you a nice start. You can use NetBeansIDE, which is recommended over command line; or you can use another IDE like Eclipse.

Comment: cd C:\java 
it tells me that C:\Documents and Settings\Admin>cd C:\java>
The syntax of the command is incorrect.
C:\Documents and Settings\Admin>C:\Documents and Settings\Admin\Desktop\java
'C:\Documents' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
C:\Documents and Settings\Admin>cd java
The system cannot find the path specified.
i saved the script that i need to convert to .class to my desktop in the folder java what am i doing wrong? i followed the instructions on the webpage.

Comment: ugh, imma try it again just using the "helloworld"

Comment: C:\Documents and Settings\Admin>cd C:\java
The system cannot find the path specified.

C:\Documents and Settings\Admin>

Comment: @plr: Look at the Troubles and Solutions page, and if that doesn't help you, then ask the question at superuser.com, because it's about installation and Windows command prompt etc not about programming.

Comment: @plr: Good for you, IDEs are great!

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile the java using javac (the java compiler)  You can get it as part of the JDK which you can get from Oracle (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)

You'll need to run a command like the following

```
javac foo.java
```

Which will produce a corresponding foo.class

Comment: will the javac allow me to laod a script into it then compile them into .class (byte) code which i then need to compile into my gamebots scripts?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to compile multiple java files into class files then you follow  given procedure.

**Syntex:**

```
javac <options> <source files>
```

**Example:**

```
javac -cp -d classfolder *.java
```

here

```
options are -cp (copy), -d (directory), classfolder (directory name)

source files are * (all) .java files
```